# Buying ethereum on Metamask or Coinbase

Tags: metamask, gas, fees, coinbase

What is the cheapest way to buy ethereum? Straight through metamask or through coinbase and then transfer it to metamask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't "buy" eth from metamask.  You have to connect your metamask to an exchange and make the purchase.  Coinbase allows you to buy it and transfer it into a coinbase wallet for free.  You'll pay a transaction fee to send it to your metamask wallet.